# JSON syntaxError: (Code was working fine and just went out)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, sql, json

The following code was working fine and randomly went out. I am getting the following error:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input
> at Function.parse [as parseJSON] (<anonymous>)
> at Object.success (customers:606:38)
> at c (jquery-3.6.0.min.js:2:28327)`

The error is on (var res = jQuery.parseJSON(response).

Below is the code:

```
   $(document).on('submit', '#saveCustomer', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
    
   var formData = new FormData(this);
    formData.append("save_customer", true);
    
    
   $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "code.php",
                data: formData,
                processData: false,
                contentType: false,
                success: function (response) {
                    
                    var res = jQuery.parseJSON(response);
                    if(res.status == 422) {
                        $('#errorMessage').removeClass('d-none');
                        $('#errorMessage').text(res.message);
    
                    }else if(res.status == 200){
    
                        $('#errorMessage').addClass('d-none');
                        $('#customerAddModal').modal('hide');
                        $('#saveCustomer')[0].reset();
    
                        alertify.set('notifier','position', 'top-right');
                        alertify.success(res.message);
    
                        $('#myTable').load(location.href + " #myTable");
    
                    }else if(res.status == 500) {
                        alert(res.message);
                    }
                }
            });
        });
```

I've searched the web and watched videos on similar issues, but nothing is working. I've played around with it by adding (.done functions) and still nothing. Again, the code was working fine and just started getting the error.

Comment: Open up your browser's developer console, and check the Network tab for the response of the request to `code.php`. What are you getting?

Comment: If the code worked and there's been no change to the code, then it's possible that the *data* is breaking your JSON.

Comment: As the error is on `jQuery.parseJSON(response)`, what *exactly* is the value of `response`?

Comment: @aynber getting status code: 302 (failed to load response data: No content available because this request was redirected)

Comment: So the issue is not with your javascript here (unless the URL has changed), but something to do with `code.php` redirecting. You're going to have to track down what the issue there is.